# What is the significance of PV in Enthalpy (H=U+PV)? Are we adding work twice in the equation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I have 3 questions:

Enthalpy is defined as:

*H = U + PV*

1. What exactly does *PV* signify?

Also from the First Law of Thermodynamics

*∆U = q + w*

*w* here means work (done by, say, the system).
So,
*∆H = q + w + ∆(PV)*
2. In the above equation are we adding work twice?
I asked chatGPT about it, it said we are not.
I need a more deeper explanation of what the distinction between *PV* and *w* is.
There seems to be a distinction between the *PV* work in

*w = -P∆V* (if *PV* work is being done ex: gas expansion or compression) and

the *PV* term in

*H = U + PV*

3. What is this distinction?
   Could someone please explain with examples.

Comment: U is internal energy of an object. H includes squeezing by pressure - atmospheric in particular. BTW this was likely asked here like half a dozen times :/

Comment: Not twice, it cancels out if the pressure is the same before and after (and you keep the sign conventions straight).

Answer (score 2):

Your equations should read $$\Delta U=q-\int{P_{ext}dV}$$ and $$\Delta H==q-\int{P_{ext}dV}+\Delta PV$$If $P_{ext}=P=const, $, these equations reduces to $$\Delta U=q-P\Delta V$$and $$\Delta H=q$$